# Java, Proper data structure to represent a column family

Tags: java, oop, data-structures, cassandra

I am trying to find out the best data structure to represent a `cassandra` column family.

My table schema is like this:

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS test.test (
cname1 varchar,
cname2 varchar,
cname3 bigint,
cname4 bigint,
cname5 bigint,
cname6 boolean,
cname7 bigint,
......(70 more)
cnamex boolean,
PRIMARY KEY (cname1, cname2,cname3)
);
```

each column name has its own type like `varchar` `bigint` or `boolean`. In `java`, how to develop a neat data structure to represent such a table, and then I can easily access to a column name and also know its 'type', so that I can do other things against them like `insert` operation.

Normally I will do something like this:

```
public class table{
    String cname1 = "cname1";
    String cname2 = "cname2";
    ......
}
```

But then I cannot know the `type` of each column.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a simple POJO bean that you have shown above is good approach.
If you want the type of the field at rune time then you can use reflection API.

Comment: what do you mean by reflection API? Any example?

Comment: refer the link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldTypes.html